# Could not start Default Compiler: PdfLaTeX

Tags: miktex, texstudio, editors

I've been using TeXstudio without any problems for a while.
Now, whenever I try to compile some documents I get this error:

```
"Could not start Default Compiler:PdfLaTeX:
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmeode "Name_Document".tex
```

And the message I get is:

```
"Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
Process exited with error(s)"
```

Also, if I click on Help-->Check LaTeX Installation I get:

```
"Could not start :: pdflatex -version"
```

I've also tried to download again the last version of TeXStudio, but nothing changed. My test code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\title{\textbf{Titolo}} 
\author{Autori} 
\date{\today} 

\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\clearpage 
Questo è il mio primo documento in \LaTeX. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: Have you installed [MikTeX](http://miktex.org/)?  TeXstudio is only an editor.

Comment: Try to run pdflatex on a command line to find out it everything is correctly installed and if your document compiles.

Comment: Yes, I had. How can I check that MikTeX 2.9 is working properly?

Comment: I ran pdflatex on command line and I got the same: " Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed. You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help."

Comment: Did you get a log-file? Can you make a screenshort of the pdflatex run on the terminal?

Comment: Also try to do a full update of MikTeX, it may help solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

After installing portable MiKTeX I had the same problem running `texify` with a parameter `–-interaction=…` I have disabled lines

```
// IfStr("%$('%!9-No_Interaction');","1",!"=",>
//  !|LetReg(4,'%$("TeX-Opt");--interaction=nonstopmode');|,>
//  !|LetReg(4,'%$("TeX-Opt");--interaction=errorstopmode');|);
```

in `PDFTeXify.edt` and have no problems.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).